# Android - ImageView how can i get the camera picture? where resultCode is 0 and requestCode is 2?

Tags: java, android, linux, android-intent

Getting resultCode= 0 and requestCode = 2, cant get the picView with picture.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    final int PIC_CROP = 2;
    private Uri picUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }

    /**
     * Click method to handle user pressing button to launch camera
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {     
            try {
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle user returning from both capturing and cropping the image
     */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            }
            else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        } else {
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - resultCode return: " + resultCode  +" requestCode: " + requestCode;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show(); 
        }
    }    


    /**
     * Helper method to carry out crop operation
     */
    private void performCrop(){
        try {
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);  
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }    

}
```

***EDIT:*** (added as following where data.getData() is null always)

```
final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {     
            try {
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                         data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                         data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the video capture
            } else {
                // Video capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
            picUri = data.getData();
            performCrop();
        }
        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        }
    } else {
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - resultCode return: " + resultCode  +" requestCode: " + requestCode;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show(); 
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
        ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);         
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5991757/1696704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If resultCode is 0 then it means your invoked activity was cancelled. Either they must have pressed back button, orso to come back to this activity. Changes are your implementation is wrong.

Comment: Please see my EDIT, its returning Null always after passing the borders.

Comment: Did you use data.getExtras() ? What did it return?

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2: its giving me snapshot of the picture. But i cant crop it shows directly the image.

Comment: Image that i took, was Green on right, but in snapshot it shows Green on left. There is not exact image its showing.

Comment: I don't think there is anything that this code has to do which the swapping of the image. Check the image in the gallery with your image.