# How to implement Log out functionality

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am making a kind of Simple Login Registration app.Now I am implementing log-out functionality in it. On Logout button click it should navigate to login screen..How to do that.I am new to Android help will be appreciated

---

Comment: Using intent you can do that

Comment: Um... do the same thing as Login, but in reverse? "Login" and "Logout" do not mean anything explicitly to an Android application, so these terms must mean something specific to _your_ application. With that in mind, do you truly believe you've provided enough detail for anyone to answer you in your context?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=log+out+functinality+in+android&oq=log+out+functinality+in+android&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2j62l3.6307j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 what else do you want ? have you tried searching ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This worked for me, try this :

```
Intent loginscreen=new Intent(this,Activity.class);
loginscreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(loginscreen);
this.finish();
```

Comment: u can add loginscreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); if above does not work

Comment: you have two vertical bars (|) in your comment, but I suspect you really only want one... otherwise your added flags will be == 1 rather than either value.

Comment: What is that **SearchHelper.logout=1;** BTW

Comment: I have come to following complete class..Am I right

public class Welcome1 extends ListActivity
{

 Button btnLogout;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        
       btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 btnLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
 Intent loginscreen=new Intent(this,Welcome1.class);
 loginscreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(login);
 
this.finish();
        });
 }
 }

Comment: its startActivity(loginscreen); and not startActivity(login);

Comment: whats the output did it worked?

Comment: @benilMathew I have corrected the code i told by you..but still there are errors in codes.

Comment: @adward can u plz tell us which line is giving error?

Comment: Your corrected code    public class Welcome1 extends ListActivity { 
 Button btnLogout;
 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  btnLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout); 
 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

 Intent loginscreen=new Intent(this,Welcome1.class); 
 loginscreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
 startActivity(login);
 this.finish(); });

 } 
 }

Answer (score 2):

When the log out button is pressed clear the data in the SharedPreference(if you are using it ) then using intent navigate log in page

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, login.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: but i use activity then why its returning always 0 and 2 ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523751/android-imageview-how-can-i-get-the-camera-picture-where-resultcode-is-0-and

Comment: i didnt get your question !!

Comment: This code makes no sense.. what exactly do you want ? Where's onCreate ? when do you want to call it ? can you make things clear ?

Answer (score 0):

When you press "login" you start a new Activity, right?

Just use `finish();` in the new Activity, it will finish/quit it, and return to the last active activity (the login-activity).